# equivalent of Oracle's DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name() in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I'm trying to come up with a function to verify the object identifier name. Like in Oracle, if a given identifier associated with any sql object (tables, functions, views,... ) It returns the name as it is else error out. Following are few examples.

```
SELECT SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME('DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name') FROM DUAL;
   SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME('DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME')
   DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name

SELECT SYS.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME('unknown') FROM DUAL;
ORA-44002: invalid object name
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent, but if you know the expected type of the object, you can cast the name to one of the [Object Identifier Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)

For tables, views and other objects that have an entry in pg_class, you can cast it to to `regclass`:

```
select 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass;
select 'public.some_table'::regclass;
```

The cast will result in an error if the object does not exist.

For functions or procedures you need to cast the name to `regproc`:

```
select 'my_schema.some_function'::regproc;
```

However, if that is an overloaded function (i.e. multiple entries exist  in `pg_catalog.pg_proc`, then it would result in an error *more than one function named "some_function"*. In that case you need to provide the full signature you want to test using the type `regprocedureregprocedure` instead, e.g.:

```
select 'my_schema.some_function(int4)'::regprocedure;
```

You can create a wrapper function in PL/pgSQL that tries the different casts to mimic the behaviour of the Oracle function.

---

The [orafce](https://github.com/orafce/orafce#user-content-dbms_assert) extensions provides an implementation of `dbms_assert.object_name`

Comment: orafce's implementation doesn't identify functions.

Answer (score 2):

For tables, views, sequences, you'd typically cast to `regclass`:

```sql
select 'some_table_I_will_create_later'::regclass; 
ERROR:  relation "some_table_I_will_create_later" does not exist`. 
LINE 1: select 'some_table_I_will_create_later'::regclass;
               ^
```

For procedures and functions, it'd be a cast to `regproc` instead, so to get a function equivalent to `DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name()` you'd have to go through [the full list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-oid.html) of what the argument could be cast to:

```
create or replace function assert_sql_object_name(arg text) 
returns text language sql as $function_body$
select coalesce(
   to_regclass(arg)::text,
   to_regcollation(arg)::text,
   to_regoper(arg)::text,
   to_regproc(arg)::text,
   to_regtype(arg)::text,
   to_regrole(quote_ident(arg))::text,
   to_regnamespace(quote_ident(arg))::text )
$function_body$;
```

[These functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) work the same as a plain cast, except they return `null` instead of throwing an exception. `coalesce()` works the same [in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) as it does [in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COALESCE.html), returning the first non-null argument it gets.

Note that `unknown` is a [pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html#DATATYPE-PSEUDOTYPES-TABLE) in PostgreSQL, so it doesn't make a good test.

```sql
select assert_sql_object_name('unknown');
--  assert_sql_object_name
-- ------------------------
--  unknown

select assert_sql_object_name('some_table_I_will_create_later');
--  assert_sql_object_name
-- ------------------------
--  null

create table some_table_I_will_create_later(id int);
select assert_sql_object_name('some_table_I_will_create_later');
--      assert_sql_object_name
-- --------------------------------
--  some_table_i_will_create_later

select assert_sql_object_name('different_schema.some_table_I_will_create_later');
--  assert_sql_object_name
-- ------------------------
--  null

create schema different_schema;
alter table some_table_i_will_create_later set schema different_schema;
select assert_sql_object_name('different_schema.some_table_I_will_create_later');
--              assert_sql_object_name
-- -------------------------------------------------
--  different_schema.some_table_i_will_create_later
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/M3-1ZzOv)